# Using array in Rails JSONB column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, jsonb

I want to store an array of objects in JSONB column in PostgreSQL. I'm using Rails 5.2. I'm using a custom serializer that ensures the value assigned to a JSONB field is an Array not a Hash. And I'm getting an error when assigning something like `[{a: 1}]` to the field. Here is the code:
**model**:

```
class Printing
  serialize :card_faces, CardFacesSerializer
end
```

**serializer**:

```
class CardFacesSerializer
  include JSONBArraySerializer

  def allowed_attributes
    %i[name image]
  end
end
```

**serializer concern**:

```
module JSONBArraySerializer
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def initialize(data)
    return [] if data.blank?

    if data.is_a?(String)
      json = Oj.load(data, symbol_keys: true)
    end
    raise ArgumentError, "#{json} must be [{},{}], not {}" if json.is_a?(Hash)
    # Will only set the properties that are allowed
    json.map do |hash|
      hash.slice(self.allowed_attributes)
    end
  end

  class_methods do
    def load(json)
      return [] if json.blank?
      self.new(json)
    end

    def dump(obj)
      # Make sure the type is right.
      if obj.is_a?(self)
        obj.to_json
      else
       raise StandardError, "Expected #{self}, got #{obj.class}"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When evaluating:

```
pr = Printing.first
pr.card_faces = [{hay: 12}]
pr.save!
```

I get an error:

> StandardError: Expected CardFacesSerializer, got Array

I don't think it's clear for me how dump/load work. Why `dump` is being called during save? How can I fix my code to work properly?

**UPDATE**
I managed to make it work with this code of serializer concern:

```
module JSONBArraySerializer
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  class_methods do
    def load(data)
      return [] if data.blank?

      if data.is_a?(String)
        json = Oj.load(data, symbol_keys: true)
      end
      raise ArgumentError, "#{json} must be [{},{}], not {}" if json.is_a?(Hash)

      # Will only set the properties that are allowed
      json.map do |hash|
        hash.slice(*allowed_attributes)
      end
    end

    def dump(obj)
      # Make sure the type is right.
      if obj.is_a?(Array)
        obj.to_json
      else
       raise ArgumentError, "Expected Array, got #{obj.class}"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I believe, `load` is called when AR object is instantiating and `dump` when saved. So `dump` should await for `Array` (desired column value) not `self` (Serializer).

Comment: Also, I think _serialization_ is not needed here. When you have `JSONB` column, you can just check column value by custom validation. https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you're storing an `array`, why use a `JSONB` column and not an `array` column? Also, why use a `concern` and why not include the `concern` code in your `serializer`?

Comment: @jvillian because I want to store an array of _objects_ as you can see in my code `[{},{}]` and I don't want to serialize objects into strings as it's costly and it won't be searchable and indexable.

Comment: You can also use gem `activerecord_json_validator` (or underlying gem `json-schema`) for extended validation of your `JSONB` column.

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk yeah, thanks for the tip, I saw it but I don't like external dependencies in such simple cases. I finally made it work. have a look at my updated question.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use serialize with JSON/JSONB columns.

> Keep in mind that database adapters handle certain serialization tasks
>   for you. For instance: json and jsonb types in PostgreSQL will be
>   converted between JSON object/array syntax and Ruby Hash or Array
>   objects transparently. There is no need to use serialize in this case.
>   https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html

`serialize` is an old hack used to store JSON/YAML/whatever in string columns. Seriously - don't use it. It will just lead to issues with double conversion.

What you are doing should instead be handled by a regular model validation and / or a custom setter.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation